# Cannot access my (old GAE) project in BigQuery UI

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

My goal is to load a Cloud DataStore backup into BigQuery. I could successfully do the DataStore backup.

My problem now is that from the Developer Console, when I pick ' Big Query' in the left navigation, the BigQuery web UI does not open at the right project.
The URL actually contains the right project number, but the selected project is not the correct one.
If I want to select it in the dropdown ' Switch to project', I do not see it.

What can I do to select this project in BigQuery?
Is it due to the fact that it is very old and uses the App Engine free tier? It has a valid Billing account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the BigQuery API enabled on that project? If not, BigQuery will pretend the project doesn't exist.

Comment: That was the reason indeed. Thanks for the support, I hope the answer will be useful to others.